# Getting a Null error when trying to pass some parts of a List to another List

Tags: apex, null-pointer

I'm getting an 'Attempt to de-reference a null object' error.

I think the problem is where I'm passing an Account Object of one List to another List within an if statement. I only want the results that also return a child query. 
Using the query in the Query Editor gives a result as expected. Although the debug of the result, 'schoolQuery' seems to not include any School_Visit__c objects. Not sure if that's related?

What would be the best method to get this data?

```
public List<Account> schoolInfo {get;set;}
public List<Account> schoolQuery {get;set;}
public List<School_Visit__c> visitInfo {get;set;}
```

In Constructor->

```
String queryInfo = 'SELECT Lat__c, Lng__c, ID, Name, '+
            '(SELECT School__c, ID, Date__c, Class_Year__c, Topic__c, Requires_Irish_speaker__c, Preferred_Time__c '+
            'FROM School_Visits__r WHERE Status__c LIKE \'Open%\') '+
            'FROM Account WHERE RecordType.ID = \''+SchoolID+'\'';

    System.debug(queryInfo);
    schoolQuery = Database.query(queryInfo);
    System.debug(schoolQuery);
    prepareVisitInfo();
```

Method->

```
public void prepareVisitInfo() {

    for( Account school : schoolQuery) {

        if(!school.School_Visits__r.isEmpty()) {

            schoolInfo.add(school);   

        for(School_Visit__c visit : school.School_Visits__r) {

            visitInfo.add(visit);
            System.debug(visitInfo);
        }
       }      
    }     
 }
```

Comment: What line is the error happening on? and where is `visitInfo` getting instantiated? i.e. `visitInfo = List<School_Visit__c>();`

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Silly mistake, I guess I was getting away with it from only using them via Database.query previously.

Thanks very much.